# Select Tag with Object - Thymeleaf and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying  to change the code of this example [thymeleafexamples-stsm](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm), so I changed enum type for class type:

Type.java

```
public class Type { 

    private Integer id; 
    private String type; 
   ...getters and setters 
}
```

SeedStarterMngController.java

```
@ModelAttribute("allTypes") 
    public List<Type> populateTypes() { 
        Type type1 = new Type(); 
        type1.setId(1); 
        type1.setType("OUTDOOR"); 

        Type type2 = new Type(); 
        type2.setId(2); 
        type2.setType("INDOOR"); 

        List<Type> tipos = new ArrayList<Type>(); 
        tipos.add(type1); 
        tipos.add(type2); 
        return tipos; 
    }
```

seedstartermng.html

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
    <option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" th:value="${type}" th:text="${type.type}">Wireframe</option>
</select>
```

So, I can't Add Seed Starter.

My Output html is

```
<select id="type" name="type">
    <option value="thymeleafexamples.stsm.business.entities.Type@2c08cec0">OUTDOOR</option>
    <option value="thymeleafexamples.stsm.business.entities.Type@26cf024">INDOOR</option>
</select>
```

and the error is

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type thymeleafexamples.stsm.business.entities.Type for property type;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [thymeleafexamples.stsm.business.entities.Type] for property type: no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

How I can do to be mapped to type correctly? I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error message basically says Spring don't know how to convert the string `thymeleafexamples.stsm.business.entities.Type@2c08cec0` into an instance of Type. This is a bug on your code because it doesn't make any sense trying to do so.

You're not supposed to use the `toString()` value of Object as a form dropdown identifier. You need to have a (much) better strategy for the code to identify the Type selected by user.

Common approach is to use the `id` attribute:

```
<option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" th:value="${type.id}" th:text="${type.type}">Wireframe</option>
```

When the form is submitted, you then need to retireve an instance of Type based on its id name on your controller

Comment: Adding the ID in the th:value, it is exposing that value to the browser. I was trying not to show any ID at all. That's why I use "@SessionAttributes" in the controller and "@InitBinder".

Comment: Then do whatever you need so you can pass some sort of string identifier into the dropdown and get it back when the form is posted. The string `thymeleafexamples.stsm.business.entities.Type@2c08cec0` will simply never become a java object. Period. Consider java enum, serialization, using another non-sensitive identifier etc.

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is old but below answer may help someone as I could not find it easily.

To solve this issue, Thymeleaf uses Formatters to convert between Object and String.

- In display phase (GET), Formatter Service will convert Object to
  String.
- In submitting phase (POST), Formatter Service will convert    String
  back to

  object.

First implement Formatter service for your Class to be used in  tag:

```
@Service
public class TypeFormatter implements Formatter<Type> {

    @Autowired
    TypeService typeService;//Service -> DB

    @Override
    public String print(Type object, Locale locale) {
        return (object != null ? object.getId().toString() : "");
    }

    @Override
    public Type parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(text);
        return this.typeService.get(id);//return Type object form DB
    }
}
```

It is very simple class with two methods:

- **print**: converts object to string.
- **parse**: converts string to object.

Now, we've to tell Spring-Thymeleaf abbout our formatter or we may call it converter. To do that we've to register this formatter in our WebConfig (Configuration class whic extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = { "your package" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

....
    //Formatters

    @Autowired //Without autowire, this solution may not work
    private TypeFormatter typeFormatter;

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(typeFormatter);
    }
}
```

Now our solution is ready to be implemented in html file but how to tell Thymeleaf to apply conversion?
Answer is by using **th:field="*{type}"** attribute and using Double-bracket syntax **th:value="${{type}}"**:

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
    <option th:value="NULL" th:text="---Select Type---"></option>
    <option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" th:value="${{type}}" th:text="${type.type}">Wireframe</option>
</select>
```

- **th:field="*{type}"** is applying registered Formatter service by default. It will convert type to String (here the string will be Type Id)
- **th:value="${{type}}"** is converting type to string as well.
- In submit, Spring will use the Formatter service to convert Id back
  to object.

Last thing to tell, sometimes we want to add a header to the dropdown list like "-----Select Type-----" in order to prevent default selection as well as explain to user. In this case you must set **th:value="NULL"** unless you'll get conversion error.

Comment: Want to following your instruction but I can't find TypeService class. Could you tell which jar is it in? Thanks.

Comment: Solved, this is just a DAO class, need implement myself.