# Access Embedded Object Attributes in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have the following `Animal` Class that a Many to One association with a Zoo

```
@Entity(name = "Animal")
public class Animal{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Animal_Id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Animal_Name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Zoo_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Zoo zoo;

}
```

Zoo.java

```
@Entity(name = "Zoo")
public class Zoo{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Zoo_Id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Zoo_Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Zoo_address")
    private String address;
}
```

What I am trying to do is access all attributes of `Zoo` within a Thymeleaf template and display them in a dropdown

If I were to use a `Map`, I could access an attribute with the following:

```
 @ManyToOne
 @OneToMany(targetEntity = Zoo.class)
 Map<Long, String> zooMap= new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();;
```

The template would look like so:

```
<select id="zoo">
    <option value="" th:text="-Select-"></option>
    <option 
        th:each="zoo : *{zooMap.entrySet()}" 
        th:value="${zoo .key}"  
        th:text="${zoo .value}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Is there a solution to grab these values with just the embedded `Zoo` Object?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is old but I will include some examples how to achieve it.

In Thymeleaf it is possible to access "embedded" objects which are part of the form backing bean with certain limitations. There are couple of ways how to do that. Using the  example with some extra relations. There will be bi-directional mapping for one to many relationship. One animal belongs to one Zoo. Then we have a list of all animals in the Zoo object.

```
@Entity(name = "Animal")
public class Animal{

   @Id
   @Column(name = "Animal_Id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "Animal_Name")
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "Zoo_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Zoo zoo;

}



@Entity(name = "Zoo")
public class Zoo{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Zoo_Id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "Zoo_Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Zoo_address")
    private String address;      

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Animal.class)
    private Collection<Animal> animals;

 }
```

Lets imagine we have a form with animal and we would like user to assign it to existing Zoo. We need to inject list of all available Zoos to the model and then iterate this collection in the option element.

Common approach is to use id of the object as value instead the object reference. After submitting the form, the child animal object is correctly populated in the form backing bean.

If you would like to use reference to the object, you can check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30430218/931030 which explains how to create your own converter.

```
 <form th:object="${animal}">

    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- other standard attributes -->
    <!-- ... -->

    <select th:field="*{zoo.id}">
       <option th:each="zoo : ${zooList}" th:value="${zoo.id}" th:text=${zoo.name}></option>
    </select>
 </form>
```

Accessing first animal in our collection:

```
 <form th:object="${zoo}">
      <input type="hidden" th:field="*{animals[0]}"/>
 </form>
```

Accessing a first object in the collection using position defined in variable:

```
 <form th:object="${zoo}">
     <div th:with="someIndexSetByVariable=1">
      <input type="hidden" th:field="*{animals[__${someIndexSetByVariable}__]}"/>
     </div>
 </form>
```