# dropdown's selected value not passed to controller using thymeleaf + spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

This is my view code. for populating dropdown component with values passed from controller.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/product2}" method="post">
  <select th:field="*{product3}" th:remove="all-but-first">
            <option th:each="productItem : ${productItems}"
                    th:value="${productItem.productId}" th:text="${productItem.description}">Product 1</option>
            <option value="">Product 2</option>
            <option value="">Product 3</option>
    </select>

  <button type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

This is my Controller which is responsible for populating values for dropdown and upon submitting form printing selected value in dropdown.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");             
    Product wildFire = new Product();
    wildFire.setProductId("WF-458");        
    wildFire.setDescription("WildFire");
    Product weapon = new Product();
    weapon.setProductId("WE-81");
    weapon.setDescription("Weapon");
    List<Product> productItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
    productItems.add(weapon);
    productItems.add(wildFire);
    model.addObject("productItems", productItems);
    model.addObject("product3", new Product());
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/product2", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String showProduct(@ModelAttribute(value="product3") Product product, ModelMap map) {        
    System.out.println(product.getDescription());
    return "products";
}
}
```

This is Product's Data class. just for reference

```
public class Product {

private String productId;
private String description;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product [id=" + id + ", version=" + version + ", productId=" +  productId + ", description="
            + description + ", imageUrl=" + imageUrl + ", price=" + price + "]";
}
```

}

**Issue**: Upon submitting this form, not getting selected value (of products dropdown) on controller side, from various source figured out that component binds with object by using syntax th:field="*{object}". please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form you need to set `th:object`, otherwise you can't access posted value this way. Also you must create backing bean of the form. Something like this :

```
private class ProductForm implements Serializable {
    ...
    private Product product3;
    ...    
}
```

Your form will have `th:object` of type `ProductForm`. Note that `Spring` don't understand what kind of object you passed to `product3` so you must also [provide a converter for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416987/spring-form-binding-how-to-do-it-cannot-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-strin) :

```
<form th:object="${productForm}" class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/product2}" method="post">
<select th:field="*{product3}" th:remove="all-but-first">
        <option th:each="productItem : ${productItems}"
                th:value="${productItem.productId}" th:text="${productItem.description}">Product 1</option>
        <option value="">Product 2</option>
        <option value="">Product 3</option>
</select>
```

Controller code :

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");             
Product wildFire = new Product();
wildFire.setProductId("WF-458");        
wildFire.setDescription("WildFire");
Product weapon = new Product();
weapon.setProductId("WE-81");
weapon.setDescription("Weapon");
List<Product> productItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
productItems.add(weapon);
productItems.add(wildFire);
model.addObject("productItems", productItems);
model.addObject("product3", new ProductForm());
return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/product2", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String showProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="productForm") ProductForm productForm, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap map) {        
return "products";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton :-), it actually helped me and worked, Thumbs up, Just for reference - For Conversion from String to MyType(Product in this case) i used Solution suggested by Ayman Al-Absi in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234357/select-tag-with-object-thymeleaf-and-spring-mvc.