# Spring JPA, Thymeleaf - Bind Form List to Entity with EmbeddedId (OneToMany; ManyToOne)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, thymeleaf

I have created a Thymeleaf form which has a field that accepts multiple values. I am attempting to map this list of fields to a JPA entity, but I keep getting the following error:

```
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'equipmentExerciseList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'myproject.model.EquipmentExercise' for property 'equipmentExerciseList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/ctwRpskAeIU?t=4803) tutorial, and a difference I see is that one of my entities has an embedded id, so I figure that must be causing my issues.

Basically, I want to insert a new exercise into the database, with the exercise containing a list of required equipment. The required equipment must be chosen from a list existing in the database.

### **Tables**

I have an entity, Exercise, which logically can be performed with multiple props/pieces of equipment. Similarly, the pieces of equipment can be associated with multiple exercises. I have created a join table to handle this relationship, and I also have a third table which controls the equipment that can be selected:

[image: [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewrjv.png)]

### **Code**

#### **Entities**

Exercise.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Exercise")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Exercise implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "exercise_name")
    private String exerciseName;

    // Others removed for brevity  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exercise")
    private List<EquipmentExercise> equipmentExerciseList; 
}
```

EquipmentExercise.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "EquipmentExercise")
@ToString
public class EquipmentExercise implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    EquipmentExerciseId equipmentExerciseId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("exerciseName")
    @JoinColumn(name = "exercise_name")
    Exercise exercise;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("equipmentName")
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_name")
    Equipment equipment;

}
```

EquipmentExerciseId.java

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class EquipmentExerciseId implements Serializable {
    
    @Column(name = "equipment_name")
    String equipmentName;

    @Column(name = "exercise_name")
    String exercise_name;
}
```

Equipment.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Equipment")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Equipment {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "equipment_name")
    String equipmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EquipmentExercise> equipmentExerciseList;

}
```

### Attempted Solution 1

At first I retrieved a list of potential props from the Equipment table and used that to populate the options on the Thymeleaf form:

#### Controller

```
 @GetMapping("/stretch")
    public String addStretch(Model model){
        List<Equipment> availableEquipmentList = equipmentService.findAllEquipment();
        EquipmentExercise equipmentExercise = new EquipmentExercise();

        model.addAttribute("exercise", new Exercise());
        model.addAttribute("availableEquipmentList", availableEquipmentList);
        model.addAttribute("EquipmentExercise", equipmentExercise);

        return "/add";
}
```

#### Thymeleaf Form

```
 <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exercise.equipmentExerciseList" class="form-label">Prop(s)</label>
    <select th:field="${exercise.equipmentExerciseList}" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name = "exercise.equipmentExerciseList">
       <th:block th:each="equipment : ${availableEquipmentList}">
               <option th:text="${equipment.equipmentName}" th:value="${equipment.equipmentName}" />
       </th:block>
    </select>
</div>
```

but I got the error from above.

### Attempted Solution 2

I did some digging here and discovered that the error probably is arising because the program did not know how to convert from Equipment to EquipmentExercise. So, I tried using an EquipmentExercise object instead of the Equipment object in the form, but I am still effectively getting the same error, just with a different object as the source of the error.

```
 @GetMapping("/stretch")
    public String addStretch(Model model){
        List<EquipmentExercise> availableEquipmentList;

        EquipmentExercise equipmentExercise = new EquipmentExercise();
        EquipmentExerciseId equipmentExerciseId = new EquipmentExerciseId();
        equipmentExercise.setEquipmentName = "Test";
        equipmentExercise.setEquipmentExerciseId(equipmentExerciseId);
        availableEquipmentList.add(equipmentExercise);

        model.addAttribute("exercise", new Exercise());
        model.addAttribute("availableEquipmentList", availableEquipmentList);

        return "/add";
}
```

#### Thymeleaf Form

```
 <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exercise.equipmentList" class="form-label">Prop(s)</label>
    <select th:field="${exercise.equipmentList}" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name = "exercise.equipmentList"  >
       <th:block th:each="equipmentExercise : ${equipmentExerciseList}">
           <option th:text="${equipmentExercise.getEquipmentExerciseId().getEquipmentName()}" th:value="${equipmentExercise}" />
       </th:block>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### Error

```
Field error in object 'exercise' on field 'equipmentExerciseList': rejected value [EquipmentExercise(equipmentExerciseId=EquipmentExerciseId(equipmentName=Test, exerciseName=null), exercise=null, equipment=null)]; codes [typeMismatch.exercise.equipmentExerciselist,typeMismatch.equipmentExerciseList,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [exercise.equipmentExerciseList,equipmentExerciseList]; arguments []; default message [equipmentExerciseList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'propList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'myproject.model.EquipmentExercise' for property 'equipmentExerciseList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

---

**Update**

I have confirmed my suspicion that the issue stems from the composite id, but I do not yet have a solution.

To confirm, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234357/select-tag-with-object-thymeleaf-and-spring-mvc/30430218) similar question, where one of the answers explains that the th:value is supposed to map to a primary key, which Spring then uses behind the scenes to generate the requested object. I am guessing that the th:values I've provided are too ambiguous (due to the composite key) for Spring to map correctly.

I looked into a custom converter, and was able to get Spring to generate an Exercise object using this, but understandably, the values the other fields in my EquipmentExercise class didn't map

```
@Override
public EquipmentExercise convert(String equipmentName){
    
    EquipmentExercise equipmentExercise = new EquipmentExercise();
    EquipmentExerciseId equipmentExerciseId = new EquipmentExerciseId();
    equipmentExerciseId.setEquipmentName(equipmentName);
    equipmentExercise.setEquipmentExerciseId(equipmentExerciseId);
       
    return equipmentExercise;
}
```